# Rails jobs with Sidekiq in Google Cloud Run not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-cloud-platform, redis, sidekiq, google-cloud-run

I've a working Rails application in Google Cloud Run using:

- Cloud Build
- Cloud Registry
- Cloud Run
- Cloud SQL
- Cloud Storage
- Cloud Key Management Service
- Cloud Scheduler

I've configured Sidekiq to execute some jobs in background but I get this error in Cloud Run logs when I'm trying to execute Sidekiq jobs.

```
Redis::CannotConnectError (Error connecting to Redis on 127.0.0.1:6379 (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)):
```

I let you here my deployment setup:

**cloudbuild.yaml**

```
steps:

# Decrypt Rails Master key file
- name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud
  args: ["kms", "decrypt", "--ciphertext-file=./config/master.key.enc", 
         "--plaintext-file=./config/master.key",
         "--location=us-central1","--keyring=project_name", 
         "--key=rails_master_key"]

# Decrypt Whale on Rails service account credentials
- name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud
  args: ["kms", "decrypt", "--ciphertext-file=./config/project_name_runner.key.enc", 
         "--plaintext-file=./config/project_name_runner.key",
         "--location=us-central1","--keyring=project_name", 
         "--key=project_name_runner_key"]

# Build image with tag 'latest' and pass decrypted Rails DB password as argument
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args: [ 'build',
    '--tag', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/project_name:latest',
    '--build-arg', 'DB_PWD',
    '--build-arg', 'RUBY_VERSION=${_RUBY_VERSION}',
    '--build-arg', 'PG_MAJOR=${_PG_MAJOR}',
    '--build-arg', 'NODE_MAJOR=${_NODE_MAJOR}',
    '--build-arg', 'BUNDLER_VERSION=${_BUNDLER_VERSION}',
    '--build-arg', 'RAILS_ENV=${_RAILS_ENV}',
    '--build-arg', 'REDIS_URL=${_REDIS_URL}',
    '--build-arg', 'DATABASE_HOST=${_DATABASE_HOST}',
    '--build-arg', 'DATABASE_USER=${_DATABASE_USER}',
    '--build-arg', 'DATABASE_NAME=${_DATABASE_NAME}',
    '.'
  ]
  secretEnv: ['DB_PWD']

# Push new image to Google Cloud Registry       
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args: ['push', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/project_name:latest']

secrets:
- kmsKeyName: projects/project_name/locations/us-central1/keyRings/project_name/cryptoKeys/db_pwd_key
  secretEnv:
    DB_PWD: "db_password"

substitutions:
  _RUBY_VERSION: '2.7.0'
  _PG_MAJOR: '11'
  _NODE_MAJOR: '12'
  _BUNDLER_VERSION: '2.1.2'
  _RAILS_ENV: production
  _REDIS_URL: redis://redis:6379/
  _DATABASE_HOST: /cloudsql/project_name:us-central1:project_name-production
  _DATABASE_USER: production_user
  _DATABASE_NAME: project_name-production
```

**entrypoint.sh**

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

cd /usr/src/app

# Create the Rails production DB on first run
bundle exec rake db:prepare

# Do some protective cleanup
> log/production.log
rm -f tmp/pids/server.pid

# Run the web service on container startup
# $PORT is provided as an environment variable by Cloud Run
bundle exec rails server -b 0.0.0.0 -p $PORT

# Run sidekiq in production
bundle exec sidekiq -C config/sidekiq.yml
```

**Dockerfile**

```
# Leverage the official Ruby image from Docker Hub
# https://hub.docker.com/_/ruby
ARG RUBY_VERSION
FROM ruby:$RUBY_VERSION

LABEL maintainer="myemail@gmail.com"

ARG PG_MAJOR
ARG NODE_MAJOR
ARG BUNDLER_VERSION
ARG RAILS_ENV

# Add PostgreSQL to sources list
RUN curl -sSL https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | apt-key add - \
  && echo 'deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ stretch-pgdg main' $PG_MAJOR > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list

# Install recent versions of nodejs (10.x) and yarn pkg manager
# Needed to properly pre-compile Rails assets
RUN (curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_$NODE_MAJOR.x | bash -) && apt-get update && apt-get install -y nodejs 

# Add Yarn to the sources list
RUN (curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | apt-key add -) && \
    echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list && \
    apt-get update && apt-get install -y yarn

# Install production dependencies (Gems installation in
# local vendor directory)
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY Gemfile Gemfile.lock ./
ENV BUNDLE_FROZEN=true
RUN gem update --system && \
    gem install bundler:$BUNDLER_VERSION
RUN bundle install

# Copy application code to the container image.
# Note: files listed in .gitignore are not copied
# (e.g.secret files)
COPY . .

# Pre-compile Rails assets (master key needed)
RUN yarn install
RUN RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile

# Set Google App Credentials environment variable with Service Account
ENV GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/usr/src/app/config/sunne_cms_api_runner.key

# Setup Rails DB password passed on docker command line (see Cloud Build file)
ARG DATABASE_NAME
ARG DATABASE_HOST
ARG DATABASE_USER
ARG DB_PWD
ENV DATABASE_PASSWORD=${DB_PWD}
ENV DATABASE_NAME=${DATABASE_NAME}
ENV DATABASE_HOST=${DATABASE_HOST}
ENV DATABASE_USER=${DATABASE_USER}

# Setting up Rails environment
ENV RAILS_ENV=${RAILS_ENV}

# For now we don't have a Nginx/Apache frontend so tell 
# the Puma HTTP server to serve static content
# (e.g. CSS and Javascript files)
ENV RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES=true

# Redirect Rails log to STDOUT for Cloud Run to capture
ENV RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT=true

# Designate the initial sript to run on container startup
RUN chmod +x /usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh"]
```

Comment: Cloud Run does not support background jobs. Your container starts with an HTTP request and ends when the request returns. Do not expect anything more after the request returns. Cloud Run is not an operating system, task scheduler, background thread processor, etc. Read this to understand what Cloud Run can/cannot do https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/container-contract

Comment: I have a project that is trying to do something similar - I've included some alternate solutions in my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cloud Run does not support background jobs. Your container starts with an HTTP request and ends when the request returns. Do not expect anything more after the request returns.

Cloud Run is not an operating system, task scheduler, background thread processor, etc.

Read this to understand what Cloud Run can/cannot do:

[Cloud Run Container Contract](http://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/container-contract)

Answer (score 4):

As [John Hanley](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60303701/1303595) mentions, Cloud Run doesn't support background processing. Depending on your requirements, you have a few options though.

### Option 1

Use a separate service to run your background jobs, potentially using [Cloud Pub/Sub](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/tutorials/pubsub) service-to-service messaging subscriptions to broadcast when the job is ready. Your web service can return a handle/ID to the subscription, which the caller can use to listen for updates.

The background service itself can be run in its own Cloud Run container, if appropriate, or since you appear to be using NodeJS, you could package it as a [Cloud Function](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/background).

### Option 2

Move your container to a solution that supports background processing, like App Engine or Kubernetes Engine (GKE). These two have very different pricing models to Cloud Run however, and depending on your usage patterns could end up being significantly more expensive. (This [Google blog post](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/containers-kubernetes/when-to-use-google-kubernetes-engine-vs-cloud-run-for-containers) breaks down the differences between GKE & Cloud Run.)

GKE can handle a single-container setup without any need for you to learn or mess around with Kubernetes directly. But if your project architecture changes, or you need to do any configuration or troubleshooting, there could be a significant learning curve involved.

### Option 3

Rewrite your code to use synchronous processing instead, maintaining the request until the job is complete. This would only be feasible if your jobs will definitely always complete before the timeout (60s?), and if your end use-case allows for it. This one is the simplest solution, but the most restrictive and prone to user-facing errors.